# Wanting to overwrite a function from parent theme but functions within it are not defined yet

Tags: wordpress

I have a function I want to overwrite in wordpress from my parents theme, just wanting to make some edits to it. However when I copy it across to my functions.php file in its child, functions it uses within it are not yet defined so it errors out. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I have a bunch of code in my child theme already, the problem is I want to edit a parent's function, so I pasted it into the child theme, but because it calls other functions inside of it, I get defined errors.

Comment: I have no workaround for instance, sorry…